# Compactly supported functions are dense in $L^p$ where $0<p<1$

Tags: functional-analysis

I’m clear that we can use the cutoff functions to prove that $C_0^\infty$ is dense in $L^p$ for $1\leq p<\infty$. But how to prove $C_0$ is dense in $L^p$ for $0<p<1$ ?

Comment: Is it not true that $C_0^{\infty} \subseteq C_0$? What stops us from approximating an $L^p$ functions by a compactly supported **smooth** function, if we are asked to approximate it using a compactly supported continuous function?

Comment: What is $C_0$? In many texts $C_0$ stands for continuous functions that vanish at infinity. That is space is not fully contained in any $L_p$ in general. If you are referring to the space of continuous functions with compact support (usually denoted by $C_{00}$ then the proof of its density in $L_p$ (0<p<1) is exactly the same as for $p\geq1$ using Lusin's theorem (See the proof for $p\geq1$ in Rudin's RCA and see that it can be extended to $0<p<1$

Comment: Thanks to Aniruddha Deshmukh and Oliver Díaz. Your comments help a lot.